# </div> closure tag parsed as text node

Tags: html, parsing, dom, rendering

Honestly, this is just weird.
I had

```
<div id="files"></div>
```

In the Web Inspector I saw the `</div>` as a text node and therefore rendered as text on the page!

**I double-checked the whole file for misclosed tags or missing doctype but everything was correct**.

The problem has now disappeared by just writing - by hand - the file anew. Saving it with a different encoding had not worked. What do you think it could have been?

Comment: Use the w3c validator most often it will answer your questions 
http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: by "writing the file anew", do you mean re-typing, by-hand, the whole file, or do you mean just re-saving the file?

Have you run a diff between the "old" and "new" files?

Comment: I am not used to such tools, so I haven't thought of that. The "broken" version of the file was deleted, in case the problem shows up again I will run a diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually happens when some invisible characters somehow sneak into the code. You can't read it, but the browser can.

Other possible causes are that the `<` character of the `</div>` isn't what you think it is (perhaps this: `ᐸ` or `˂`.

To confirm, you should try to **[validate your HTML markup](http://validator.w3.org)**, and/or use a smart IDE.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I've noticed strange characters in various .js files that would generate syntax errors.